# Swift: Forbid use of original class name after creating a typealias

Tags: swift, type-alias

**Is it possible in Swift to forbid the use of the original class name in my program after the creation of a typealias?**

Hi,

To avoid inconsistent use of class name in my program I would like to force the systematic use of the alias name instead of the original class name in my program. Is it possible to do that?

I am using an external library, in which there is a class that does not exactly what it is supposed to do: **the name of that class in the library seems incorrect to me**. How can I handle this?

eg. a class `Dog` that has a function `meows` instead of `barks`, and I want to rename it `Cat` and then call exclusively `Cat` in my program.

Comment: This sounds extremely like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain *why* you want to forbid this? Is there some name conflict going on? If so please show a [mcve].

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "after" the creation of a typealias? There is no concept of *time* when compiling your code. *Where* (which scopes) do you want to forbid this? If you can answer that by [edit]ing, it will be much clearer.

Comment: If you want “to force” your code to use a new name for a class then you can simply rename it and your app won’t compile until you fix all the places you use the old name! You can even use Xcode’s refactor tool and it should rename all the occurrences, including in storyboards.

Comment: I edited my question to explain further: how can I rename a non-meaningful class name in an external library?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it would be much improved with [a bit of code that demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Sweeper There *is* a concept of time, or at least compilation order. Obviously, the `Cat` type alias cannot be established without referencing `Dog`, and the code for `Dog` itself has to be compiled, but AFAICT the OP would like for code that uses `Cat` to not have access to `Dog`.

Answer (score 4):

Applying a consistent style like this is the job of a linter, not the compiler. For [swiftlint](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint), you'd write a rule something along these lines. (This is untested, but based on the `pirates_beat_ninjas` example from the documentation.)

```
custom_rules:
  cats_not_dogs:
    included: 
      - ".*\\.swift" 
    name: "Use Cat rather than Dog"
    regex: "Dog"
    match_kinds:
      - identifier
    message: "Use Cat rather than Dog."
    severity: error
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am using an external library, in which there is a class that does not exactly what it is supposed to do: the name of that class in the library seems incorrect to me. How can I handle this?

One option is to create your own library that wraps the offending one and only exposes your names.

Since your question is tagged [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) I'll assume that we're actually talking about Swift packages here. Let's say that the package you're using is called `Canine`, and that it includes a class `Dog`, which you would prefer to call `Cat`. You can create a new package, say, `Feline`, that has a file `Feline.swift` like:

```
import Canine

public typealias Cat = Dog
```

Now you can add the `Feline` package to your app, and `import Feline` to whichever source files need it. The `Canine` package will be added to the app as a dependency, but as long as you don't add `import Canine` to your source files, the compiler will prevent you from using `Dog` directly.

This seems like a lot of trouble to go to just because you don't like the name of a class. Even so, I can imagine some reasons why it might be worth the effort, e.g.:

- Many of the names in `Canine` are poorly chosen;
- Your company was recently acquired, and you want to rename the types in your library to include the new name or hide the old one;
- You have several different libraries that you want to build your app against without having to change the names in the source code. (Protocols might be a better option in this case.)